# How to pump streams with offset and length in vert.x?

Tags: java, kotlin, stream, vert.x

I'm porting a kotlin rest server to Vert.x, but I have some trouble finding an alternative to `InputStream.skip()`, `OutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len)` and how to append to a file on disk.

Is it possible using the `Pump.pump()`?
Do I have to override the `ReadStream` and `WriteStream`?

My old code is:

```
    val fromOffset = FROM_OFFSET.getLongParam(req, false, 0)
    val toOffset = TO_OFFSET.getLongParam(req, false, -1)

    val component = repository.getComponent(contRep, docId, compId)

    component.inputStream.use { input ->
        res.outputStream.use { output ->
            input.skip(fromOffset)
            val buffer = ByteArray(64 * 1024)
            var len: Int
            var read = 0
            do {
                len = input.read(buffer)

                // Check offset
                read += len
                if (toOffset in 0..(read - 1))
                    len -= (read - toOffset).toInt()

                if (len > 0) output.write(buffer, 0, len)

            } while (len > 0)
        }
    }
```

And, to append to a file:

```
    inputStream.use { appendStream ->
        FileOutputStream(componentFile, true).use { outputStream ->
            appendStream.copyTo(outputStream)
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you porting it to Vert.x/Java or to Vert.x/Kotlin? If it's the later, I suggest to just wrap your code in a worker verticle and continue with other tasks. If it's the former,  you can use `vertx.fileSystem().readFile` for similar results.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin Vert.x/Kotlin, but I think every Vert.x Java API is usable from Kotlin too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a file in append mode. Then when you call `write` the buffer goes to the end of the file:

```
vertx.fileSystem().open(fileName, new OpenOptions().setAppend(true), ar -> {
  if (ar.succeeded()) {
    AsyncFile writestream = ar.result();
    // If you write here it will be at the end of the file
  }
});
```

For skipping, just use `AsyncFile#setReadPos`:

```
vertx.fileSystem().open(fileToRead, new OpenOptions(), ar -> {
  if (ar.succeeded()) {
    AsyncFile readstream = ar.result();
    rs.setReadPos(offset);
  }
}
```

When this is done you can use the usual pump code:

```
Pump pump = Pump.pump(readstream, writestream);
readstream.endHandler(v -> {
  // Done
});
pump.start();
```

These are all Java snippets but you'll easily convert to Kotlin syntax.

Comment: Thank you @tsegismont, and how to limit the amount of bytes to write?

Comment: You can't do it with a pump directly, you'd have to work with data `pause`/`resume` and `drainHandler` yourself (see https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#streams)